# How do I create a node from a class?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Trying to finish my doublely linked list program, but I don't really know how to create a node using a class. I've only ever used sctructs.

DoubleNode.h:

```
#ifndef DOUBLE_NODE_H_
#define DOUBLE_NODE_H_

template<class ItemType>
class DoubleNode
{
private:
   ItemType item;
   DoubleNode<ItemType>* prev;
   DoubleNode<ItemType>* next;

public:
   DoubleNode(const ItemType& anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr, DoubleNode<ItemType>* nextPtr);
   ~DoubleNode();

   ItemType getItem() const;
   DoubleNode<ItemType>* getPrev() const;
   DoubleNode<ItemType>* getNext() const;

   void setPrev(DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr);
   void setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType>* nextPtr);
};

#endif
```

DoubleNode.cpp:

```
#include "DoubleNode.h"

template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>::DoubleNode(const ItemType& anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr, DoubleNode<ItemType>* nextPtr) :
                item(anItem), prev(prevPtr), next(nextPtr)
{
}

template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>::~DoubleNode()
{
    this->prev = this->next = nullptr;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType DoubleNode<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
   return this->item;
}

template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>* DoubleNode<ItemType>::getPrev() const
{
   return this->prev;
}

template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>* DoubleNode<ItemType>::getNext() const
{
   return this->next;
}

template<class ItemType>
void DoubleNode<ItemType>::setPrev(DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr)
{
    this->prev = prevPtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
void DoubleNode<ItemType>::setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType>* nextPtr)
{
    this->next = nextPtr;
}
```

These two files were provided by my professor, and I need to implement another class called DoubleListInterface.h. I'm working on that right now, but I don't really know if I've even created the nodes right.

Here's my DoubleList.cpp insertFront implementation so far:

```
template<class ItemType>
bool DoubleList<ItemType>::insertFront(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* n; // Creating pointer to node
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* head;
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* tail;

    // If list is empty, this is the first node
    if (itemCount == 0){
        n = new DoubleNode<ItemType>; // Creating node
        n->this->item(newEntry); // Putting item in node

        n->prev = NULL; // First node, so prev is null
        head = n; // Both head and tail would be at this node
        tail = n;

        itemCount++; // Increment itemCount
    }
    else{
        DoubleNode<ItemType>* temp = new node; // Creating a filling new node
        temp->this->item(newEntry);

        temp->this->setPrev(head->this->getPrev()); // Set prev to the prev of head pointer
        temp->this->getNext() = this->head; // Make next point to the head
        head->this->getPrev() = temp; // Point prev of the old head node to the newly created node
        head = temp; // Temp is the new head

        delete temp; // Delete temp pointer
        temp = NULL;

        itemCount++; // Increment intemCount
    }

    return true;
}
```

I get a lot of errors when I run this, the majority of which are "expected unqualified-id before 'this'" on every place that I use a `this` pointer. Don't really know what that means either, but I'd really like to know if I'm creating the nodes right. Thanks for anything you can contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point to **this**.

For example, you wrote

```
temp->this->item(newEntry);
```

The correct way to do this is

```
temp->item(newEntry);
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't even really know how to use the this pointer. I thought that you had to use it when you were trying to access a function from the parent class, but we never actually went over how to use it in class. I'll give this a try, thanks! @helper

Comment: @Sam Here is some documentation on `this`. The top half will read like it's written in Martian, so skip down to the examples and then go back up to the top once you've got a handle on what the examples are teaching.

Comment: @Sam `this` is a pointer to the current 'location' in the program--so if we're in an object's method then `this` is a pointer to that object. `temp` is already a pointer to a `DoubleNode` object, which you can use to reference its properties and methods. There is no need for a call to `this`, since you already have a pointer to the object (`temp`). (Also, you aren't in the right context for `this` to work how you want to anyway.) And as user45... suggested, looking at some examples is a great idea!

Comment: @helper Thanks so much, that makes a lot more sense.